# How set bar color based on specific multiple weekday value

Tags: excel-2007

I have an excel sheet with data.
column A have date and column B have some value, both make a bar chart with same bar color.

I want to convert all date to weekday and make a separate bar color according to my desired weekday.

Example: i want to make separate bar color if bar belongs to sunday,tuesday,friday.

How can i achieve this??

[this is my excel sheet (Sheet1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skTRv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks i sort out my problem through vba side. Still hope for better opinion.